# Laravel calculator can't give 8 numbers after the dot

Tags: laravel

I have create a simple price calculator in laravel. I have some problem when the price goes below the 0.00

Result of calculator must be:

```
0.00000005
```

But now its giving:

```
5.0E-8
```

Can anyone help me to get the result with 8 digit?

Comment: If it is a price calculator, surely 2dp is sufficient?

Comment: Hello @Peppermintology i need 8 digit behind the dot

Answer (score 0):

Use printf with the appropriate format specifier:

```
printf("%.8f", 5 / 1e8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/sprintf) to get desired output.

Note that output will be displayed as string.

```php
sprintf('%.8f', $val)
// ex. 0.00000005

number_format($val, 8)
// ex. 0.00000005
```